# Help me understand the timeline of the Cohen Family, specifically, when did they marry and have Seth?

Tags: chronology, the-o.c

I am watching The O.C. again and I can't piece the timeline of Sandy and Kirsten's marriage.

Clues: 1. They have their 20th wedding anniversary in Season 2 meaning Seth is 16-17 years old, so they've been married at least 4 years prior to him being born.

2. They met at Berkeley during the 1984 Presidential Elections as we see through flashbacks in Season 4.
3. Also in Season 4 Kirsten celebrates her 40th birthday by which time Seth is 19 years old.
4. The Cohen family lived in Berkeley until Seth was 2 years old and they moved to Newport.

So if Sandy and Kirsten met when she was 18 and she was 40 when Seth was 19, she must have had him when she was 21. So the Cohens were living together with a baby while they attended Berkeley university?